# Im Getting Issues With make file

Tags: makefile

Can I get help I don't exactly know how to compile stuff well I do but this one is just confusing me but anyways so im new to make file but when I run make boot.firm it says https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8O0U.png I haven't tried anything because I have no idea what to do can someone please help me out because I am a noob at compiling lol here is the main error:

> make[1]: Entering directory
> '/home/Glitcher/Desktop/Luma3DS/Luma3DS/sysmodules' make[2]: Entering
> directory '/home/Glitcher/Desktop/Luma3DS/Luma3DS/sysmodules/loader'
> bps_patcher.cpp arm-none-eabi-g++: No such file or directory

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You haven't given us enough information to solve the problem, but it looks as if one of your source files isn't where your build system expects it to be. Where did these makefiles come from? Who gave you this task? If you're new to compiling, then mastering a makefile system with at least three levels of recursion that doesn't work is going to be a big project.

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. Please do not use images to illustrate your error messages. Copy-paste them in your question and format them properly. I suggest that you first visit the [help centre](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to understand how to ask questions here.

Comment: According the error messages you get you are trying to compile for an ARM hardware target but you do not have the compiler for this (or it is not on your `PATH` and your shell does not find it). Check maybe that `arm-none-eabi-g++` is properly installed and your `PATH` contains the directory in which it resides.